# SAMSUNG A11 hang on logo after flash

Tags: samsung, downloading, device-firmware

Hy to every one. after flashing Samsung A11 SM-A115F with Android Q10 ,Samsung Device struck at logo.
i have try to flash different firmware
first download file from [Easy Firmware](http://easyfirmwarex.com/)
and after that try to flash file from [SamFirm](http://samfirms.com/)
need help

Comment: problem is with bootloader has downgrade protection, check your screen in download mode for version